# Instagram API Tag Search

Tags: facebook-graph-api, hashtag

I am not able to find user_id that needs this url request.
https://graph.facebook.com/ig_hashtag_search?user_id=XXXXX&q=coke

I need to get tag_id in order to get posts with this tag.

Where can I find it? I have tried many users id but I get the following error:
"Param user_id is not a valid Instagram User ID"

Anyone can hep me?

Thank you

Francesc

Comment: The one of the Business Account or Creator Account, on whose behalf you are making the request ...?

Comment: Hello CBroe. I have tried Facebook business account, Instagram business account and the error still appears.

Comment: You need to get it via the connected Facebook page, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/getting-started#5--get-the-page-s-instagram-business-account